# Rational application developer(RAD) 9.6 cannot use Websphere Application Server 8.5?

Tags: websphere, rad

I installed the **Rational application developer(RAD) 9.6**, and find that there is no *WebSphere Application Server 8.5* in the option list when config the new server.

#### Define new server options

[image: Define new server options]

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere 8.5 traditional is available with RAD 9.6. I have it here. You do have to select it during the installation process. Or you can use Installation Manager to Modify and add it:

[image]